# JAVA. Записать число в файл, используя FileOutputSteam

Tags: java, потоки-данных, fileoutputstream, java-output-stream

Нужно записать число в файл, используя FileOutputStream.

```
 BufferedReader readerr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String fileName = readerr.readLine();
 FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
 int a = 3;
 outputStream.write(Integer.toString(a).getBytes());
```

Перебрал кучу вариантов, ничего не подходило пока не подсмотрел эту конструкцию:

```
 outputStream.write(Integer.toString(a).getBytes());
```

Может кто-нибудь объяснить сию конструкцию? Есть ли другие варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Создаем объект для чтения с консоли:***

```
 BufferedReader readerr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

*Тут `System.in` - источник данных, `InputStreamReader` - поток чтения из источника, `BufferedReader` - буфферизует наш поток.*

***Чтение строки из консоли:***

```
 String fileName = readerr.readLine();
```

*По названию переменной можно понять, что это имя файла.*

***Теперь мы открываем поток на запись и хотим записать в него число:***

```
 FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
 int a = 3;
 outputStream.write(Integer.toString(a).getBytes());
```

Смысл всего этого в том, что мы читаем и пишем байты. Когда вы хотите передать какую-то информацию в файл, вы должны изначально преобразовать ее в байты. Т.к. наш файл содержит текстовую информацию, то это должна быть строка.

***Это значит, что мы должны наше число преобразовать в строку, а потом получить из нее байты:***

```
outputStream.write(String.valueOf(3).getBytes());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь исчерпывающий ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Объясняю:

```
int a = 3;
String aToString = Integer.toString(a); // записываем 'a' в строку
byte[] bytes = aToString.getBytes(); // получаем массив байт из строки
outputStream.write(bytes); // записываем байты в файл
```

Вы используете метод `write` класса `FileOutputStream`, который получает на вход массив байт. Сначала вы `int a` записываете в строку (`Integer.toString(a)`), а затем получаете байты этой строки, которые и записываются в файл.

Более простой вариант решения вашей проблемы:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt")){
    out.println( /* что угодно, что нужно записать в текстовый файл */ );
}
```

Благодаря `try-with-resources` можете не беспокоиться о том, что нужно будет что-то не забыть закрыть.

Если вам нужно использовать именно `FileOutputStream`, то вам нужно изначально получить массив байт из того, что нужно записать в файл.
В примере выше я пояснил приведенную вами конструкцию, и, я думаю, проблем больше возникнуть не должно. Впредь просто сначала формируйте строку, которую нужно записать в файл, а затем получайте из неё массив байт и также записывайте.

Comment: Спасибо большое, и за наводку на альтернативный метод решения.

Comment: @Donatell0 если ответ удовлетворяет вопросу, поставьте галочку, она чуть левее вопроса :)

Comment: я бы с радостью, но мне пока что такая привилегия недоступна :)

Comment: @Donatell0 принимать ответы можно сразу, вроде бы :)